# (How) can a package on CRAN import a package not on CRAN?

Tags: r, cran

Packages on the Comprehensive R Archive Network (CRAN) can obviously directly import other packages that are on CRAN.

Can packages on CRAN also import packages that are **not** on CRAN? - if not, I guess the options are:

- get the other package onto CRAN, or
- abstract out the necessary parts to include directly (rather than import the entire package)
- other methods?

I'm interested because sometimes a contribution makes more sense sitting in a separate package, especially if the contribution is likely to be used in its own right, or in other packages.

Comment: Related to the second bullet point---I've seen packages on CRAN that "suggest" packages not on CRAN to handle this. Where features from those packages are required, the authors use `requireNamespace()` to make functions fail gracefully if those additional packages are not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) specifies that you can include an `Additional_repositories` field in the DESCRIPTION file.

However, the [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) says:

> Packages on which a CRAN package depends should be available from a mainstream repository: if any mentioned in ‘Suggests’ or ‘Enhances’ fields are not from such a repository, where to obtain them at a repository should be specified in an ‘Additional_repositories’ field of the DESCRIPTION file (as a comma-separated list of repository URLs) or for other means of access, described in the ‘Description’ field.

- "mainstream" here presumably means CRAN (and maybe? Bioconductor) ([this bioc-devel thread from 2015](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2015-March/007064.html) suggests that both CRAN and Bioconductor are "mainstream")
- "depends" here means Imports/LinkingTo/Depends

I can't think of any solutions beyond the ones you suggest (get the package on CRAN *or* incorporate the necessary code in your package).

Comment: Curious 'mainstream repositories' includes github or github's new(ish) package service..

Comment: I don't know ("mainstream" doesn't occur anywhere else in the repository policy), but I very much doubt it. You could ask the CRAN maintainers, or (better) post a question on `r-package-devel@r-project.org`.

Comment: @user5783745: A "repository" is something well-defined which `install.packages()` and `update.packages()` can use with the repos option set properly to download actual _realease_ from -- either source or binary.  This is rather different from an github repository, or other version-controlled source code repository.