# How to import data.table development version hosted on github into an r-package?

Tags: r, data.table, r-package

## Outline

data.table development version v1.14.9 provides the env argument - a new interface for programming on the language with data.table (see this [vignette](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html)). This is especially useful for deploying data.table within functions. I want to use this interface within a package that I am actually developing. But I don't manage to import the data.table development version into the package.

## What I tried

- I updated data.table with `data.table::update_dev_pkg()` and tested a function with the new env argument - everything works fine.
- I tried to use the very same function within package via load_all() - I get an error.
- I added `Remotes: github::Rdatatable/data.table` to the DESCRIPTION file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773066/r-package-building-how-to-import-a-function-from-a-package-not-on-cran), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493388/create-an-r-package-that-depends-on-another-r-package-located-on-github) and [here](https://pak.r-lib.org/reference/pak_package_sources.html#the-remotes-field)
- I included the `Additional_repositories: https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table` to the DESCRIPTION file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549652/how-can-a-package-on-cran-import-a-package-not-on-cran).
- I changed it to `additional_repositories: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table.git` after reading [this](https://devtools.r-lib.org/articles/dependencies.html) and [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)
- I also read what Wickham writes in his R-packages book on importing nonstandard dependencies (see [this](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-in-practice.html)) - what he says ist roughly similar to the point I mentioned on the Remotes-field above.

But no avail. I'm not sure, what exactly goes into these fields to get the latest data.table development version into my package.

## Minimal example

The following function replaces numerical codes with character-values according to a definition-file (.lbl) that is deployed to a data-file (.dtt).

```
# libraries (for interactive use only, do not deploy inside package)
data.table::update_dev_pkg()
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

# function (use this inside the package)
make_labels <-
    function(.dtt,.lbl){
        f <- 
            function(.dtt,clm,val,lbl){
                .dtt[
                    ,clm := as.character(clm)
                    ,env = list(clm=clm)
                ][
                     clm == val
                    ,clm := lbl
                    ,env = list(clm=clm,val=val,lbl=I(lbl))
                ]
            }
        purrr::pwalk(.lbl,f,.dtt)
    }

#sample data
dtt <-
    data.table::data.table(
         v1 = rep(1:2,5)
        ,v2 = rep(1:5,2)
    )        
lbl <-
    data.table::data.table(
         clm = c(rep("v1",2),rep("v2",5))
        ,val = c(1:2,1:5)
        ,lbl = letters[1:7]
    )

#deploy function
make_labels(dtt,lbl)
```

This works without any complaints, when the function is loaded interactively. However, when ...

- data.table is imported via the `NAMESPACE` file import mechanism (by adding `Remotes: github::Rdatatable/data.table` to the DESCRIPTION file) and subsequently
- the function is loaded by `devtools::load_all()` within the package

R throws the following error:

```
> make_labels(dtt,lbl)Error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, `:=`(...) 
and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular 
ways. See help(":=").
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: @konrad I added a minimal example!

Comment: Thanks. Let’s see if somebody with data.table expertise comes along. One thing I can immediately see is that you are using `library()`, which is not allowed inside a package. You must use the `NAMESPACE` file import mechanism instead. And calling `data.table::update_dev_pkg()` inside the package namespace is probably also not a good idea.

Comment: @konrad Thank you for your answer! I use neither library() nor data.table::update_dev_pkg() within the package. I just added it here to build a minimal reproducible example. I add an according comment to the code section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Following steps make the error go away:

- Put `Remotes: Rdatatable/data.table` to the DESCRIPTION file. This way the package imports the data.table development version automatically from github (no need to declare github explicitly in the DESCRIPTION file, it's the default).
- Put `#' @import data.table` on top of the function file and execute `devtools::document()`. This way roxygen automatically adds `library(data.table)` to the NAMESPACE file.

I found the solution finally by reading a data.table vignette on importing data.table into a package ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html)) as well as two stackoverflow-posts on that topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package?rq=2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package?rq=2)).

I successfully used data.table within packages before, so I thought the error is (solely) based on loading the development version into the package but infact there was a second problem: the missing NAMESPACE entry via roxygen.