# Find the last element by group in a data.table without max()

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to find the last element in a `data.table` by group in a time efficient way. I have a solution that works:

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(id = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b",3)), 
                   time = c(1:2, 1:3))
Data[, lastobs := max(time), by = id]
Data <- Data[time == lastobs]
Data[, lastobs := NULL]
```

but the `max()` by group command takes pretty long. In my still manageable dataset of 3 million observations and time being a yearmonth variable, it takes 20 seconds and I need to do it for many yearmonths. I want to move to a much larger dataset now where this becomes infeasible. I was thinking there must be a `data.table` way to do this by simply ordering the data.table by id and time and then using these `.I`, `.N`, or `.SD` shorthands that I never understand to simply keep the last element by group without having to calculate something like `max()` within each group. Is there such a solution? My attempt:

```
Data <- data.table(id = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b",3)), 
               time = c(1:2, 1:3))
Data[,.N == .I, by = id]
```

selects the last row of the first group and the first row of the second group because I don't really understand this syntax...

Edit: Checking what is wrong with GForce:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)


Matrix products: default



locale:

[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   

[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    


time zone: Europe/Berlin

tzcode source: internal


attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     


other attached packages:

[1] data.table_1.14.10


loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] compiler_4.3.2 tools_4.3.2   

> Data <- data.table(id = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b",3)), 

+                    time = c(1:2, 1:3))

> Data[verbose = TRUE, , lastobs := max(time), by = id]

Detected that j uses these columns: time 

Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 5 rows and 1 columns

0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 

Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 

lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'max(time)'

Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.

Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
memcpy contiguous groups took 0.000s for 2 groups
eval(j) took 0.000s for 2 calls

0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem you're seeing. If I run this code on my pretty old laptop even with 5 million rows and 1 million groups it takes a fraction of a second. If you run `Data[verbose = TRUE, , lastobs := max(time), by = id]` what is the output? You should see a line which says `GForce optimized j to 'gmax(time)'`. If not check your `data.table` [optimization options](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/html/datatable-optimize.html). `getOption("datatable.optimize")` should be >=2 for GForce to be on (i.e. `max()` is replaced with fast `gmax()`).

Comment: `Detected that j uses these columns: time 
Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 5 rows and 1 columns
0.010s elapsed (0.010s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'max(time)'
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  memcpy contiguous groups took 0.000s for 2 groups
  eval(j) took 0.000s for 2 calls
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)`

Comment: `> getOption("datatable.optimize")
[1] Inf`

Comment: It is running with `GForce FALSE`. On my machine I get `Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE)`. There's your problem. Is this output from running the command on the sample data you posted or your real data?

Comment: the sample data but I get the same (GForce false) message in the real data (which generally is slower than the example, probably because time is a yearmonth)

Comment: If you're talking about a `tsibble::yearmonth` that shouldn't make it much slower as it's just an integer really. If you're not getting `GForce` even with your sample data you have a problem. Are you sure that's the output of `Data[verbose = TRUE, , lastobs := max(time), by = id]`? There's also a `memcpy` in there which there shouldn't be so something strange is going on. What version of `data.table` do you have? You could try upgrading and see if that fixes this.

Comment: I have updated my Rversion which was outdated but now everything seems to be up to date and still does not use GForce, see edit above. Thanks so much for taking this much time btw!

Comment: What is the output of `packageVersion("data.table")`? Mine is 1.14.9.

Comment: > packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.10’

Comment: I removed mine and installed your version, nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help until here. I'm trying to fix this, GForce is on if I run other examples I find online. A weird bug that goes beyond this question I think...

Comment: One last try - does `Data[verbose = TRUE, , lastobs := max(x), by = id, env = list(x = "time")]` turn on GForce? If not I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: that just throws `> Data[verbose = TRUE, , lastobs := max(x), by = id, env = list(x = "time")]
Error in [.data.table(Data, verbose = TRUE, , :=(lastobs, max(x)),  : 
  unused argument (env = list(x = "time"))`

Comment: you may need to upgrade your `data.table` - I am actually using the dev version of 1.14.9 which has support for `env`. The current CRAN version should be fine.

Comment: I don't think the default version does it but the dev version did. Now, GForce is on. Thanks so much and for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77198381/how-to-import-data-table-development-version-hosted-on-github-into-an-r-package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons I've never quite understood, calls to `.SD` are relatively slow. It will be especially noticeable when those calls are inside a grouping operation in a table with many groups.

Benchmarking several options with a large dataset, including two (additional) options that avoid `.SD` calls:

```
library(data.table)

Data <- data.table(id = sample(1e5, 3e6, 1), time = runif(3e6))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  max = dt[, .SD[time == max(time)], by = id],
  order = dt[, .SD[order(-time)][1], by = id],
  SD = setorder(dt, time)[, .SD[.N,], by = id],
  duplicated = setorder(dt, -time)[duplicated(id) == FALSE],
  which.max = Data[Data[,.I[which.max(time)], id][[2]]],
  setup = {dt <- copy(Data)},
  unit = "relative",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: relative
#>        expr         min        lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
#>         max  45.5618283  44.17181  42.815332  41.820841  44.65020 37.1529480    10
#>       order 120.9743203 117.88609 112.860512 111.569424 114.80476 99.5545706    10
#>          SD  42.6016642  40.95944  38.931049  38.914373  39.36850 33.3685212    10
#>  duplicated   1.0000000   1.00000   1.000000   1.000000   1.00000  1.0000000    10
#>   which.max   0.8926029   1.02968   1.012396   1.025658   1.07502  0.9811257    10
```

More benchmarking replications, dropping the `.SD` approaches and adding the OP's solution and a `unique` option:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original = dt[,lastobs := max(time), id][time == lastobs][,lastobs := NULL],
  unique = unique(setorder(dt, -time), by = "id"),
  duplicated = setorder(dt, -time)[duplicated(id) == FALSE],
  which.max = Data[Data[,.I[which.max(time)], id][[2]]],
  setup = {dt <- copy(Data)},
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    original 1.068006 1.060215 1.113420 1.079614 1.143387 1.112775   100
#>      unique 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#>  duplicated 1.193816 1.219129 1.269957 1.241923 1.307255 1.163229   100
#>   which.max 1.036372 1.017441 1.062959 1.024766 1.090846 1.030185   100
```

All four options are nearly equivalent.

Comment: This is good - I like the `duplicated()` approach - but I would add the original approach in the question as well `Data[, lastobs := max(time), by = id]`. It wouldn't surprise me if it's the fastest of them all.

Comment: I suspect it may be, but it doesn't return an equivalent result. If the desired table contained only the rows with the maximum, an additional processing step would be required. Also, I'm replacing the `duplicated` one with a simpler `unique` approach.

Comment: Isn't that the `Data <- Data[time == lastobs]` step? Which will be slower but there's going to be a copy made at some point if you're subsetting. Or are you saying it's still not equivalent after that - what am I missing?

Comment: You are correct. I will update my post to include the original.

Comment: very cool... So there is a faster version.

Comment: One other approach which is similar to the original approach but 1) clearer and 2) slower is to use `(1:.N)==.N` as a way to find the last row. However, it's not competitive on speed so I don't recommend it for this application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data.table is sorted (if not, use `setorder`):

```
Data[, .SD[.N,], by = id]
#   id time
#1:  a    2
#2:  b    3
```

From the documentation:

"`.SD` is a data.table containing the Subset of `x`'s Data for each group ..."

"`.N` is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group."

Comment: I knew it. Still looks like vodoo to me... So .SD means I am now in the data.table of, say, id=1. Then I subset that in i by taking .N...  The comma after .N is redundant, no?

Comment: The comma after the end is needed to refer to a row.

Comment: Yes, the comma is redundant within data.tables. I like it here for readability.

Comment: huh... This was exactly the answer I'm looking for but it turns out to be much slower!

Comment: @Jakob it is slower for the same reasons as the other answer. Run `Data[verbose = TRUE,, .SD[.N,], by = id]`. You'll see it says `GForce FALSE`. I find it hard to know when `data.table` is going to use its optimisations so always use `verbose = TRUE` in situations like this to see what's happening under the hood. Also if you're doing the `setorder()` step then ordering all the data by group will be slower than just finding the max by group.

Answer (score 2):

Using `order`.

```
> Data[, .SD[order(-time)][1], by = id]
   id time
1:  a    2
2:  b    3
```

Reconsidering `max`

```
> Data[, .SD[time == max(time)], by = id]
   id time
1:  a    2
2:  b    3
```

If speed is still an issue, you could tackle the problem outside of R, e.g. using [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print; next}
     BEGIN {current_id = ""}
     $1 != current_id {
         if (max != "") print max
         max = $0
         current_id = $1
     }
     $2 > max_time {
         max = $0
         max_time = $2
     }
     END {
         if (max != "") print max
     }' foo.txt > foo2.txt
$ cat foo2.txt 
"id" "time"
"a" 2
"b" 3
```

Not sure how you have your data stored, you can save this example using

```
write.table(Data, 'foo.txt', row.names=FALSE)
```

---

*Data:*

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(id = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 3)), 
                   time = c(1:2, 1:3))
```

Comment: Note that these don't take advantage of all the `data.table` optimizations. If you run e.g. `Data[verbose = TRUE, , .SD[order(-time)][1], by = id]` the output will say,  `Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... The result of j is a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and over again for each group. When j=list(...), any names are detected, removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency. Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider changing to :=)`. Also this copies the data (`memcpy` is in the verbose output).

Comment: I'm still running speed tests but all of these solutions seem to be slower than my original attempt so far

Comment: @Jakob I'm not sure if you'll get any further in R. Maybe try _awk_ which is very fast. See edit.

Comment: @SamR Thanks for pointing to verbose mode. Feel free to contribute with suggestions for improvement.

Comment: @jay.sf I can't replicate the original approach being slow so I don't have any suggestions for improvement I'm afraid. Using `awk` is an interesting idea though - nice out of the box approach.