# data.table's gforce optimisation

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

Say I have the below

```
library(data.table)

# no of rows
x <- 1e8

# data
df <- data.table(y = sample(c(1:10, NA), x, replace = T)
                 , z = sample(c(1:10, NA), x, replace = T)
                 )
```

and that gforce optimisation is supposedly on:

```
getOption('datatable.optimize')
[1] Inf
```

Now, referring to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865457/find-the-last-element-by-group-in-a-data-table-without-max) from SamR and Jakob we should be able to see if `data.table` uses gforce while computing. For example, an excerpt Jakob posted:

```
Detected that j uses these columns: time  Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 5 rows and 1 columns 0.010s elapsed (0.010s cpu)  Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)  lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'max(time)' Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged. Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ...    memcpy contiguous groups took 0.000s for 2 groups   eval(j) took 0.000s for 2 calls 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)
```

However, when I try, `data.table` merely shows the following:

```
df[, mean(y, na.rm = T)
   , verbose = T
   ]

Detected that j uses these columns: y 
[1] 5.500079
```

this is not because of the `na.rm = T` argument which prevented gforce because Matt Dowle [said so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137591/about-gforce-in-data-table-1-9-2) and because the below also does not show a detailed message:

```
df[, mean(y)
   , verbose = T
   ]

Detected that j uses these columns: y 
[1] 5.500079
```

Furthermore, the use of `lapply` does not get us any message at all:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = T)
   , .SDcols = c('y', 'z')
   , verbose = T
   ]

          y        z
1: 5.500079 5.500274
```

Why is it I am not able to get a verbose message Jakob got ? Thank you

Comment: hi @SamR
I had 1.14.2 but have now uninstalled and re-installed. Currently on 1.14.10 Have re-run above codes and still the skimmed down messages

Comment: Your example does not use any grouping so gforce does not apply - it is for grouped operations. Try e.g. `df[, mean(y, na.rm = TRUE), verbose = T, by = z]`.

Comment: You should update to the new data.table 1.15.0.

Comment: @Roland ... I hadn't noticed, thanks for the clue that they finally released the long-in-dev version! (Finally: `env=`, `measure.vars`, `fifelse` and `NA`s, utf8 in `fwrite`, and `by=.I`, to name a few. Woohoo!)

Comment: @lotus You are right.  Just checked. Thank you

Comment: @Roland @r2evans when I re-installed `data.table` yesterday (`install.packages(data.table)`) it only gave me 1.14.10
To get anything later do I specify I want the developer version ?

Comment: 1.15.0 is on CRAN as of 30th Jan. Your CRAN mirror might not have been synced yet when you tried.

Comment: @lotus you may write your comment as an answer so question can be marked as answered then